# Mysql : How to insert a row only if an update statement affected 0 row?

Tags: mysql, insert-update

Please consider this simple example : a "User" table and a "Computer" table. A user can have 0 or N computer.

I want to update all computers for a user (from windows to mac, for example ;-), and create 1 computer if the user don't have already one.

So I can't une INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, because I don't have any duplicate key.

The dream query would be like :

```
UPDATE computer SET model='mac' WHERE user_id=1 
ON ROW_AFFECTED = 0 INSERT INTO computer SET model='mac', user_id=1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mySQL you could try it this way, that should work:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT xyz FROM TABLE WHERE col = 'xyz') THEN
    INSERT INTO....
ELSE
    UPDATE....
END IF;
```

I hope I could help you.

Comment: I was hoping a more simple solution, but it seems to be the only one. Thanks !